# How to pass a Concatenate Strings to a Function in R

Tags: r, function, character-encoding

I am having a problem of how to pass a concatenated strings that is similar to the name of the datasets in my global data. Name1 to Name12 is a dataset

```
Name1 3obs of 2variables

Name2 4obs of 2variables

...

Name12 2obs of 2variables
```

I want to simplify my code since so I made a for loop to print each dataset name

```
for(j in 1:12){
name<-paste("Name",j,sep="")
print(name)
}
```

after that I tried passing it to the function

```
for(j in 1:12){
name<-paste("Name",j,sep="")
Greetings(name)
}
```

but i encounter

```
Error in name$gender : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Greetings <- function(name){
check<-name$gender
if(check==male) cat("Greetings","Mr",name$person)
else cat("Greetings","Ms",name$person)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a problem with the String, it's totally fine. Rather you need a database for checking the gender. You cannot just call `$gender` on a string, hoping it will tell you if it's male or female. You will need a data.frame or a table where you can look up if the name is female or male.

Additionally, also `name$person` won't work, as `name` is only a String. Do not mix strings and data.frame/table.

If you already have a data.frame/table where the gender is deposited, you have to extract this value from the data.frame/table with `dataFrame[name=name,]$gender` respectively `dataFrame[name=name,]$person` where the first `name` is the column caption and the second `name` your variable, containing the name you want to examine as String.

EDIT: You need to use `eval(as.name(name))` to reference the variable, if `name` is a String containing the name of the variable.

Comment: Name1 to Name12 are already dataframes.

After passing concatenated string, i will access the dataframe in that function using the concatenated string that is the same as the name of the dataframe.

Comment: I edited the post, containing a solution for your problem. As @Symbolix mentioned, you also need to change the male into "male". To get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Greetings` function, `name` is a string, not a data.frame. Put a `print(name)` inside your Greetings function to see this.

```
Greetings <- function(name){
  print(name)
  # check<-name$gender
  # if(check==male) cat("Greetings","Mr",name$person)
  # else cat("Greetings","Ms",name$person)
}
Greetings(name)
# [1] "Name1"
```

See that this is just a string, not your data.frame

To use the string `name` to refer to your data.frame, you need to use `get()` to refer to your R object.

Consider this example data:

```
Name1 <- data.frame(gender= c("male"),
                    person= c("a"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Create a string representing the data.frame as per your original code 
## (can be done in a loop)
name <- paste("Name", "1", sep="")
```

In the `Greetings` function, you can refer to the data.frame with `get(name)`. (you also need quotes around `male`), something like

```
Greetings <- function(name){
  check <- get(name)

  ## note this will only work as expected with a data.frame 
  ## with one row.
  if(check$gender=="male") cat("Greetings","Mr", check$person)
  else cat("Greetings","Ms",check$person)
}

Greetings(name)
# Greetings Mr a
```